# adding parameter in workbook in azure log portal

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to add parameter in workbook in azure logportal.
I check this article but didnot find more example for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-workbooks#adding-parameter-sections

Below is the query of my workbook.

```
customEvents
| extend customDimensions.Properties.username == "abc"
```

I want to add the parameter for username = "pqr"

This shows syntax error.I tried adding username but that does not work.

```
customDimensions.Properties.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have username nested even further into `Properties` inside customDimensions? (is this from App Hub?)?  or is username a field in custom dimensions?

You could make a text parameter called `username` in your workbook, and then change your query to

```
customEvents
| where customDimensions.username == "{username}"
```

that would use the `username` parameter as a parameter in your query.

if username is the actual field in your custom dimensions, the above would work.  if it is indeed nested like in your question (like from App Hub to AI exports), you have one extra "hop" to grab that nested value out

```
customEvents 
| extend Properties = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions.Properties))
| extend username = Properties.username
| where username == "{username}"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. username is inside the properties which is inside the  customDimensions.I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to extend a column with `username` property and get all `username` equals `pqr`. You could test with my query. I query `EventName` under `customDimensions`.

```
customEvents 
| where customDimensions.EventName=="Heartbeat"
| extend EventName_ = tostring(customDimensions.EventName)
```

[image]

And this is my `customDimensions` properties.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply .I know i can do that with changing the query. But then how can i do this in parameter.Is there any way i can use it. I am not actually parameter like for timerange or for anything.